# NetBeans GUI Builder - Add a whole directory of images to another specific directory, so the images will be imported there

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am currently building an application, where  I want a whole directory to be imported in another one. I am working with apache commons.io library that you need to import a s a jar file.

Let's say from a directory that I will choose with a JfileChooser from GuiBuilder Netbeans into C:\output. I want all the images to be imported there. My code is not running.
When I am pressing JButton2 ( the button responsible for loading a directory I get an exception

> > Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> >         at WebAppImg.jButton2ActionPerformed(WebAppImg.java:141) ( The second line points out to : String filename = f.getAbsolutePath(); )

copyDirectoryToDirectory method maybe. But my thoughts on doing that was that when putting FileSelectionMode to be Directories_Only that the absolute path would be something like    C:\importFile and not C:\importFile\image1.jpg for example so it would not be wrong. But maybe this is the mistake?

So far, this is my code.

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:(for importing a whole directory(folder) from C:\images1 into C:\output ).        
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    //chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    //chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    //chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    //chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
try {

    File srcDir = new File(filename);
    File destDir = new File("C:/output/");

    FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(srcDir, destDir);

}
    catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: *"Apparently , it is wrong in some point.."*  Is it?  How is that apparent?

Comment: What do you mean by _"it is not running"_? Is it throwing an exception? Then give us the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your anwsers.
When I am pressing JButton2 ( the button responsible for importing directory I get an exception like that )
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at WebAppImg.jButton2ActionPerformed(WebAppImg.java:141)
 at WebAppImg.access$100(WebAppImg.java:20)
 at WebAppImg$2.actionPerformed(WebAppImg.java:55)

Comment: Here is a link that might can help you from the standard Java Library, [Copying a File or a Directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Comment: Gagandeep thanks for your help. the problem with that is that , as it states , "Directories can be copied. However, files inside the directory are not copied, so the new directory is empty even when the original directory contains files." I do not want that. I want the target directory ( for example C:/output/ ) to constantly filling is space through imports.

Comment: You forget to call  `chooser.showOpenDialog(null);` therefore `File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();` == Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String SourceDir = f.getAbsolutePath();
try {

    File srcDir = new File(SourceDir);
    File destDir = new File("C:/output/");

    FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(srcDir, destDir);

}
    catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Moskito I am sure of trying those exact lines tht you added like a thousand times. And suddenly now it works. I had showOpenDialog(null) in it. Anyways, @John and moskito I want to thank both of you! John I am taking moskito's anwser as right but I owe you big time for your great great help!!!!! Happy new year to all of ya!

Comment: Thanks and Happy new year to you !

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not using the correct `FileUtils` method. Please try using `copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir);`

**UPDATE**

If you want to copy all the files in the src directory use the method above. If you want to copy the directory let's say `C:\images` to `C:\COPIED` the `copyDirectoryToDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir);` will result in `C:\COPIED\images` since it copies the whole directory into another directory.

Here is my working example...

```
private void jFileChooser1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
  File src =  jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
  File dest = new File("C:\\COPIED");
    System.out.println(src.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(dest.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(src, dest);
        //FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(src, dest);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileChoosingFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: [stackoverflow-jchooser.zip](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/bluelotussoftware/code/stackoverflow/stackoverflow-jchooser.zip) It should only be used as a starting point. The copying should be done in a separate thread instead of the EDT.

Comment: Hello John and thanks for your help. I tried that out just now..It doesnt work because I believe the problem is on the next 2 lines:

    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

I will need to be changing those lines, and I cant figure out what can I do.

Comment: I m trying with that and I got a problem John. If i change the source into a fixed one ( say for example, C:\\images1 ) and have a fixed one for destination ( as I always have ) it WORKS perfectly! If i replace it with             FileUtils.copyDirectory(src, dest);
it returns an exception
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Source must not be null
at that exact line! 
Let;s say if I have       File src = new File("C:\\images1"); it works! But if I have  File src =  JFileChooser1.getSelectedFile(); it give me that exception..
Do you know why is that? Thanks!

Comment: The code I sent worked perfectly fine. Otherwise I wouldn't have posted it. That said, I tried picking a couple of different directories, and it copied the files with no problem. In the project I uploaded, you still need to make sure that the commons-io is available. It was not a maven project. Did you try running it from the command line to rule out the IDE? You should be able to run ant to build it directly from the project, and then run the resulting jar.

Comment: @GeorgeKourou it looks like you are doing that code in your jButton2ActionPerformed() code and not in @JohnYeary's `jFileChooser1ActionPerformed`event. In your Button event you must call `chooser.showOpenDialog(null);` first there you can choose a directory otherwise `chooser.getSelectedFile()` == Null.

Comment: Guys I am building a button in the GUI. I think @John you are building a file chooser, isnt that so? But if I build one I cannot have a small browse button to add the contents of the directory. It works that way but I want a nice looking app that adds with a broswe button its images unfortunately. Do you think that it is possible?

Comment: The FileChooser I used in the design was simply from the palette using Matisse (visual layout). I am not sure I understand your question. You are trying to create a button that opens a FileChooser? The second part of your remarks seems like you are looking for a image viewer where you can pick images. That is a totally different approach. If you are trying to make your own FileChooser that does something similar, you should examine the code for JFileChooser.